# Is there a way in excel to import a csv into another excel sheet / template

Tags: excel, csv

I am looking for a way to combine my excel template, which has all the formatting and company headers on etc, with the raw data generated from a report on one of our systems.

This way I can isolate the raw data and the pretty looks and formatting which can be externally controlled.

So basically what I want to do is,

Pull csv report from our system.
Open up excel template with table, column names, pretty logo etc.
Some how merger the csv into the table.

Print / email completed template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sf.net).  It works with xlsx files (but not xls).

It runs like this:

```
csv2odf data.csv template.xlsx output.xlsx
```

It needs one sample row of data. Use dummy numbers where numbers will go and dummy text where text will go. Format the text/numbers however you want.

If you have several rows of headers, you can tell it how many rows to skip over with the -S option like this:

```
csv2odf -S 5 data.csv template.xlsx output.xlsx
```

You also need [python](https://www.python.org/) to run it.